# phpmyadmin not working after mysql update

Tags: mysql, update, phpmyadmin

i followed [this](https://wiki.ampath.or.ke/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=70811889) guide to update my mysql form 5.1 to 5.5. After lots and lots of command and headache, i was able to upgrade mysql. i checked the version via terminal.

But now there is another problem. phpmyadmin is not working. It says

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

i searched everywher and tried various solutions like including `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in `apache2.conf` file and restared apache(it started showing 404 error). But it's still not working.

i remember the terminal was showing `phpmyadmin is broken or not fully installed`, while i was trying various solutions.

What should i do now? repair, reinstall, format??

Edit: Also now when i open terminal(Ctrl + Alt +t), it shows various errors:

```
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
uname: command not found
bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sed: command not found
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
ubc-7@ubc-7-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Does your apache error_log show you the real path where it's looking for phpmyadmin?  Is it there?

Answer (score 1):

Of the three, I prefer repair!

Looks like your phpMyAdmin was installed by the package manager, so the first thing to try is reconfiguring it. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` should accomplish that. Hopefully that will fix the error message you got that "phpmyadmin is broken or not fully installed" -- or if not, at least provide you with a more helpful message.

You may have other broken packages or missing dependencies, which you can try to fix with `sudo aptitude -f`. That will attempt to fix any broken packages.

I'm not really sure about your terminal error message. It appears that the /bin/ directory (which contains many of your system commands like ls, kill, mkdir, and many more), isn't in the list of directories used when looking for a command (the "path"). I'm hopeful that the aptitude -f will fix this too, because otherwise something really strange (and unrelated) happened to your bash configuration file.

Note that, while these are reasonably safe commands, I'm not responsible if your system explodes.